# xlrd import values, clear formatting, delete entries that are not integers

Tags: xlrd

I am trying to import integers from an Excel spreadsheet and create a list, but I need to get rid of both the formatting and other non-integer entries. I'm using xlrd and canopy.

This code:

```
    CBSAlist = []
    for value in sheet.col(0):
        CBSAlist.append(str(value).split(":")[1])
    print CBSAlist
```

Returns a list with elements that look like this:

```
"u'43100'", "u'44620'", "u'48020'", "''", "''", "''", "''", 
"''", "''", "''", "u'CBSA Code'",
```

Instead of a list of elements that look like this (which is why I split at the colon):

```
text:u'49220', text:u'16220', text:u'16940', text:u'21740', text:u'23940',
empty:'', empty:'', text:u'CBSA Code', empty:''
```

Comment: Splitting at the colon was the idea of a stackoverflow member and very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in Excel the values were listed as text, not as numbers. I changed that first and got rid of all values in the file that were not numbers. Then I split at the colon and reassigned the values as floats.